# Multihomed BGP linux router

Tags: linux, firewall, bgp, router

I'm in the process of researching solutions for a new network location rollout.

We are going to have two providers one on 100mbit and 50mbit commits..

I'm wondering what linux solution i could build that could handle that much traffic.

and also how it stacks up against say a Cisco 2821 with upgraded RAM..

Answer (score 2):

linux box on a decent hardware can handle traffic of few hundreds mbit/s without problems.

for bgp under linux there is not much choice - [quagga](http://quagga.net/).

Comment: Are people still using BIRD (http://bird.network.cz/) ?

Comment: @Tom O'Connor - only production installations of bgp routing under linux that i saw were based on quagga.

Comment: @TomO'Connor oh yes, usage of BIRD is quite heavy, take a look at this: https://www.euro-ix.net/documents/1024-Euro-IX-IXP-Report-pdf

Comment: Archive of above PDF: https://web.archive.org/web/20140525195833/https://www.euro-ix.net/documents/1024-Euro-IX-IXP-Report-pdf

Answer (score 0):

[PFSense](http://www.pfsense.org). It's FreeBSD not Linux, but if it's just a dedicated router machine, shouldn't really matter.

Comment: I wasn't aware that PFSense had BGP capability.

Comment: @Tom - it's available as the `openbgpd` package

Comment: If you're going BSD, I would suggest using olive:  http://juniperolive.blogspot.com/2009/02/juniper-olive.html

Comment: Yikes, Olive looks cool but I bet it breaks all kinds of terms, conditions, maybe even laws.

Comment: @Joe - you have to have a copy of the Juniper OS to start with, and if you have a Juniper router, surely you'd just keep it runnong on that?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why pQd said that there's no choice for BGP routing. Personally I heard about [Zebra](http://www.zebra.org/) but never about `quagga`...

Comment: quagga forked [de-facto] dead code of zebra project. see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quagga_%28software%29#Name